# incompatible pointer type?

Tags: objective-c

I am a newbie in programming, currently across some difficulties in my first school work. Can anyone tell me am I doing on the right track? The aim of this code is to do add two numbers around 70 digits which cannot be done using the int or long int type in Objective-C. The following code keeps getting warning: **incompatible pointer types returning 'NSString *__strong' from a result type 'MPInteger *'** Help please, I have already been figuring out for ages and got nothing.

**MPInteger.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MPInteger : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * description;

-(id) initWithString: (NSString *) x;
-(NSString *) description;
-(MPInteger *) add: (MPInteger *) x;
```

**MPInteger.m**

```
#import "MPInteger.h"

@implementation MPInteger

@synthesize description;

-(id) initWithString: (NSString *) x {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        description = [NSString stringWithString: x];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *) description {
    return description;
}

-(MPInteger *) add: (MPInteger *) x
{
    int carry = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int i;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int result;


    index = [description length];
    index2 = [x.description length];


    while (index2 < index) {
        x.description = [x.description stringByPaddingToLength:index withString:@"0" startingAtIndex:0];
    }

    for (i = index; i <= index || carry != 0; i--) {
        num1 = [description characterAtIndex:index];
        num2 = [x.description characterAtIndex:index];
        result = num1 + num2 + carry;
        // if the sum is less than 10
        if (result < 10) {
            NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", result];
            [description replaceValueAtIndex:index inPropertyWithKey:intString withValue:@"%@"];
            // replace the description index value with the sum
        } else { //otherwise
            NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", result];
            //getting the index'1' is the value replace the description index value
            [description replaceValueAtIndex:index inPropertyWithKey:[intString substringFromIndex:1] withValue:@"%@"];
            carry = 1;
        }
        index--; // decrement index
    }
    return description;
}
```

Comment: `num1 = [description characterAtIndex:index]; num2 = [x.description characterAtIndex:index];` that's flawed logic, you have to subtract `'0'` from both of them, as the characterAtIndex: method rerurns the char code of the character, not its numerical value.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks a lot mate! But how do I extract the numerical value out of the index of the string in order to perform addition?

Comment: didn't you write this class? You seem to have been able to implement the `add:` method - you can extract the string from the object and perform a (wrong) adding algorithm, so what's your question?

Comment: @H2CO3   'for (i = index; i <= index || carry != 0; i--) {'  ,   'int index2 = 0;' and 'if (result < 10) {' this three line is still giving me the warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'NSString *__strong' from a result type 'MPInteger *'  What's wrong with it?

Comment: these three lines can't give you such a warning - you probably misread the compiler message.

Comment: @H2CO3 num1 = [description characterAtIndex:index]; num2 = [x.description characterAtIndex:index]; I think this two line just extract the char or does this extract the numerical value to be add to perform addition? If not, how am I suppose to do it? thanks

Comment: @userXXX now look at my first comment. ***Carefully.***

Comment: @H2CO3 I just don't understand what do you mean by **you have to subtract '0' from both of them**

Comment: @userXXX you have to **subtract** from both of them `'0'`. Like `num1 = [description characterAtIndex:index] - '0';` and the same way with num2.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh, how stupid am I lol
`index = [description length];` and `index2 = [x.description length];` is giving me a warning of **Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'
Why's that the case?

Comment: @userXXX because NSUInteger is wider than `int` - elegant solution: change `int` to `NSUInteger` in your declarations. Quick'n'easy solution: ignore the warning - as long as your string won't be longer than 2 ^ 32 characters, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry to bother you again! Substraction and Addition is mostly done! Do you have any idea or algorithm about how to do multiplication and division in this same class?

Comment: @userXXX (first of all, I'd really appreciate if you accepted my answer.) Multiplication can be done digit by digit, as if you did it on paper, but beware of the multiple digit carries! Division is a bit trickier - you can realize it using reprated subtraction and shifting.

Comment: @H2CO3 I did! your answers is fabulous! For the addition one,      [description replaceValueAtIndex:index inPropertyWithKey:[intString substringFromIndex:1] withValue:@"%@"]; is causing a **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** when I try to run this class. In this statement, I wanna replace the result's right digit with the original value of that corresponding index and make carry = 1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @userXXX what is the reason of the SIGABRT? Is it an NSException? You might be very well calling an unimplemented method.

Comment: @H2CO3 I Think it is because [intString substringFromIndex:1] is not getting the right string I want?

Comment: @H2CO3 **'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x100003368> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 8.'** I think I can get the right string which is "8", but somehow it just can't replace the string? Any solution?

Comment: By the way, your code would be simpler and faster if you used a "little endian" vs "big endian" representation.  Ie, if you made the first character in the string be the least significant digit.  Then you could index forward and you would not need to pad your strings.  (But I'm guessing you've got too many alligators to fight at this point to think about draining the swamp.)

Comment: Another "by the way":  Who the heck would have you learn programming with Objective-C???  It's a horrible "first language".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your method to return an MPInteger:

```
- (MPInteger *)add:(MPInteger *)other;
```

but you finally return `description`, which is an `NSString` instance.

You perhaps meant to make an MPInteger instance out of the string before returning:

```
return [[MPInteger alloc] initWithString:description];
```

(add `autorelease` if you don't use ARC).

Comment: Is there any way I could convert the content of 'description' into MPInteger?

Comment: @user1637132 please at least remember the purpose of the `initWithString:` method you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much exactly what the error says:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * description;
[...]
-(MPInteger *) add: (MPInteger *) x
{
[...]
    return description;
}
```

You say that your `add` method will return a reference to a `MPInteger` object but your code returns a reference to a `NSString` instead.  You need to make those match, either by declaring a string type of return value for the method or by returning an instance of `MPInteger`.

Comment: How can I convert 'description' into an instance of MPInteger?

Comment: @user1637132 `return [[MPInteger alloc] initWithString:description];`

Answer (score 0):

The warning is beacuse you're returning `description` from your `add:` method but `description` is an `NSString`. You need `description` to be an `MPInteger`.

Unfortunately, `NSObject` already has a method `called`description`which returns an`NSString`. It's this method that's called each time you use`%@` in a format string i.e.

```
NSLog(@"I am %@", self);
```

will actually call `description` on `self` and put it into the string in place of the `%@`.

At the end of your method, you need to return an `MPInteger` instead of `description`. Try replacing

```
return description;
```

with

```
MPInteger newInteger = [MPInteger new];
newInteger.description = description;
return newInteger;
```

to return a new integer.